# Altium pads and holes print PDF

Tags: altium, copper, through-hole, pad

I'm trying to print a PDF to put my PCB design on copper, and I get the PDF document and everything seems to be alright but when I print my design the pads are filled in black.

PDF Output
[image]

And this is the result:

[image]

So then, how can I get the holes in the printed PDF?

Comment: This is weird. Did you notice that holes in the square pads have printed correctly and the holes in round pads haven't?
Try a different printer, maybe

Comment: I did that :P and works

Answer (score 1):

This is because the white in the round pads are drill holes - not part of the copper structure. I don't know why some of the square pads have them though.

Not sure if you can print these, but maybe try opening the CAM-files including NC drill-file and do it from there, instead of just exporting the board file to PDF.

Comment: That's what I want the drill holes, but they are covered.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, you have the issue only when you print to paper, while the PDF is correct.

The likely solution is that when you print from Adobe reader, you select the **Advanced** button in the print page, and tick the box where it says **Print As Image**.

That should force Adobe Reader to handle the masking of the holes, rather than the printer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your big component pads is not proper on footprint. You need to edit footprint of this component. These holes is not drill holes on footprint. You can cut out on pcb or you can fix on footprint.

Dont waste your time with print settings.